net::ERR_FAILED 200 error shown in the console
net::ERR_FAILED 200

Above error shown in browser console.
We are using Microsoft Azure AD. For some API call is shows above error.
Also shown access is blocked by CORS policy. But I have resolved CORS issue.
I have tried with CORS policy resolution and and also checked with certification.
